# Select rows randomly without changing the order in sql query

Tags: sql, select, random

I searched everywhere to find an SQL query to select rows randomly without changing the order. Almost everyone uses something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
```

But above query changes the order. I need a query which selects randomly among the rows but doesn't changes the order, cause every record has a date also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the random rows and then re-order them:

```
select t.*
from (select *
      from table t
      where type = 1
      order by rand()
      limit 25
     ) t
order by datecol;
```

In SQL, if you want rows in a particular order, you need to use an explicit `order by` clause.  You should never depend on the ordering of results with no `order by`.  SQL does not guarantee the ordering.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering, unless the query has an `order by`.

Comment: I want to export above query result in PHPMYADMIN but it has no sql output format but I can see sql format in other queries